# Where to put step defs in cyrpess, cucumber project - "Cant walk dependency graph"

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I just updated my project from Cypress 9.x.x to cypress 10 and managed to get the tests running, but only if the ****example.feature**** file and step definition file (**example.ts**) are under e2e folder.

Example:

```
e2e
  example.feature
  example.ts
```

If I change the structure, for example moving the step defintion to their own folder the tests fail and I get `Can't walk dependency graph:`
What I would like to do is to put the step definition files and feature files in their own folder.

Example:

```
e2e
  features
      example.feature
      example2.feature
  step definitions
      example.ts
      example2.ts
```

I've been trying to change the specPattern in *cypress.config.ts* or is it package.json that needs to be changed? I'm not sure where to do the change or if this is a good way/ best practice of the file setup in cypress 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of cypress-cucumber that is [@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor), then in your `package.json`, you have to add the path to your step definition files like this:

```js
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
  "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/step definitions/**/*.{js,ts}"
}
```